# Fargate without API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

My service's current architecture is : Client --> Service global API gateway --> GraphQL Router --> sub-Service X API Gateway --> sub-Service X Lambda. Here problem is client is going to send 20MB request but API Gateway limit is of 10MB and lambda limit is of 6MB. So I am exploring whether can I use fargate instead of lambda and can also avoid API gateway to avoid any payload limits ?

Or we are also open to use any other compute instance other than fargate which doesn't have any payload size limits.

Also, we know S3 upload is one of the solution, but due to some limitation we cannot use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing stopping you from building a GraphQL API application that runs in docker and can be deployed to AWS ECS/Fargate. You would have to build in all stuff you are currently doing in API Gateway into the application itself. You would also need to place a load balancer in front of it.